# how to set height of one row in h:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf

I want to set the height of one row in h:panelGrid.

How can i achieve this?

here are my css classes:

```
.height8 {
    height: 8px;
}

.height0 tr td{
    height: 0%
}
```

Code of the page:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="height8, height8" rowClasses="height8">
    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row" styleClass="height0"/>
    <h:outputText value=" height should be different" styleClass="height0"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Style class height0 doesn't seem to work here.   How can i set the height of particular row in h:panelGrid?

Answer (score 0):

you have two way:

**inline style:**

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="height8, height8" rowClasses="height8">
    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row" style="height: 25px"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok" style="height: 25px"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**CSS style:**

your element should have an id:

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="height8, height8" rowClasses="height8">
    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row" styleClass="customheight"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok" styleClass="customheight"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

and add this style in your CSS file:

```
.customheight{
   height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS and use a class on the row cell content:

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="This row"/>
    <h:outputText value=" is ok"/>

    <h:outputText value="This row" styleClass="alt-height"/>
    <h:outputText value=" height should be different"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

You can create a CSS rule using the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo selector to select the row you want to change the height of:

```css
tr:has(.alt-height) {
    height: ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the following style class should work

```
.height0 tr td{
    height: 0px; //or what ever height you want to set to this row.
}
```